# Weird hang-ups and loading issues for website. (GoDaddy)

Tags: javascript, html, css

[BuyTack.com](http://www.buytack.com)

In the past few weeks I have been going back and reupdating my site. It was given to me by a friend and I have been making some minor changes to keep its somewhat old look with bigger resolution and cleaned up HTML5 code.

My issue lately is that I have been going for SEO optimization and user-experience benefits by enabling compression on my site, for load times, and moving some of the code around where many websites recommend me to.

Javascript before the closing body tag, css in the head, compressed photo's via photoshop.

Now the issue, since I've recently changed and edited my .htaccess file to allow compression is that constant refreshes or consistent search bar use leads to extreme hang-ups (20s or more) and then the page would load with either a picture missing (until another refresh) or one of the scripts taking too long to run.

To give some extra detail:

- The csSearchPro was made in perl a long time ago. It has done it's
  job fine lately, until I've started messing with compression and all
  the other JS snippets I've added to the site.
- The HTML5Shiv was added for IE 7/8, since they're still some of the
  highest browser:user ratio.

**The Question**
What could be making the site hangup so much after compression, than it did before compression? Why is the search bar / images acting weird when the page is loaded multiple times?

If you need more information, please ask.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like your `awmlib2.js` file is taking about a second to load, and, your JS files aren't grouped so it isn't sending multiple requests.  Try putting all of your scripts and your stylesheets together (seperate from each other but otherwise grouped) and recreating the problematic JS file.

Comment: I'm hesitant, since that was also one of the recommendations by sites, since I am unsure if one variable in those js files might match another one if I were to combine them all into one big JS file.

Comment: No, don't combine them. Group them in the header.

Comment: Sorry, misinterpreted. Originally AllWebMenu's reqauired its JS to be put immediately after the opening <body> tag. I've learned, through another domain I own, that I can put where ever and it works just fine.

I'll give that a try and update back here.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire server is *responding* slowly try checking your .htaccess and permissions. You should also group your scripts and stylesheets, like this:

```
<!-- CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/one.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/two.css" />
<!-- JS -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/one.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/two.js"></script>
```

This will allow them to load asynchronously, i.e. all stylesheets will load at once and then all scripts at once. What I usually do is put jQuery in the header so that I can use it inline and then the rest of the scripts merged into one file (put the each in document ready handlers if possible, you won't have a variable problem) at the footer.

Comment: I would try and upvote, but reputation is low since I just got onto this site.

I am going to try this method out, since the example is  bit easier to follow.

Comment: If it is the correct answer than you can just mark it as such.

Comment: I'm honestly unsure of the encoding for AllWebMenus.

Now the permissions I'll have to look at. Since most of this has been happening recently because of the .htaccess file.